# Chef config object

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am modifying some Chef Ruby code and stumbled upon a section that looks like the following:

```
if config[:role]
    nodes_to_process = [config[:role], ]
else
    nodes_to_process = rest.get('nodes').keys()
end
```

I've printed out the values found in that array but can't understand why you would only execute that section of code based on the value found within :role.

Is this a constant that is part of the Chef or Knife class?

Thanks

Comment: From where is this snippet coming ?

Comment: New code that I have been given at my workplace

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what it is doing without any clue of the rest of the code ?

Comment: But well, I'll assume this is a knife plugin, so you can have a look [here](https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_custom.html#options). roughly I think this is to apply the command to all nodes or just a subset based on the role they have in their runlist.

Comment: @Tensibai, you were correct! Thanks

Comment: Can you copy that down to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is related to the options that you can add when creating a custom knife plugin. If I have some option named **version**, with some settings I've configured, I can then do something like:

```
What my option may look like...
option :omg,
  :short => '-V',
  :long => '--version',
  :boolean => true,
  :description => "Print items with this version or lower."

Enter the following in your terminal...
$ knife my_custom_plugin --version 1.0

In your code...
def run
  if config[:version]
    # If the version flag was passed in
    puts "Version flag passed in."
  else
    # If the version flag was not passed in
    puts "Version flag not passed in."
  end
end
```

[Custom Knife Plugin Reference](https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_custom.html#)